# GIT bash not recognizing changes to ".classpath" file via "git diff"

Tags: windows, git, git-bash, git-diff

I was using command line GIT GNU bash as GIT client, to check in my Java project that I worked on in Eclipse.

As part of the work, I changed some project build settings, which in Eclipse are recorded in a hidden (.dot) file called "`.classpath`" in the project's root directory.

***For some reason `git diff` refused to recognize the change:***

```
user@HOST MINGW64 /c/_GIT/myserver (BRANCH1)
$ git diff .classpath

<==== crickets. Empty output!!!!
```

However, I could see that the file changed, with a recent timestamp (and could prove that it changed by explicitly doing `git commit` and pushing the change):

```
user@HOST MINGW64 /c/_GIT/myserver (BRANCH1)
$ git commit -m "remove test" .classpath

[BRANCH1 bd4c1c5] remove test
 1 file changed, 28 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 .classpath

user@HOST MINGW64 /c/_GIT/myserver (BRANCH1)
$ git push
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 610 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Simple Bitbucket Commit Checker
remote: Create pull request for BRANCH1:
remote:   http://GIT_URL....
remote:
To http://GIT_URL....
   77981fe..bd4c1c5  BRANCH1 -> BRANCH1
```

GNU bash, version 4.3.46(2)-release (x86_64-pc-msys)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git diff` without any options or arguments shows the change between your working tree and the index. Most probably your changes were staged for commit (via `git add`). You could run `git status` to verify that. To see such changes (i.e. the diff between the index and `HEAD`) you should have run `git diff --staged`.